# How to retrieve the name of every customer and how many pizzas they have ordered?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to retrieve the name of every customer and how many pizzas they have ordered. NULL if no pizzas ordered.

```
SELECT blank 1
FROM blank 2(
SELECT blank 3 AS quantity
     FROM ORDERS NATURAL JOIN ORDERCONTENTS
     GROUP BY blank 4) as quantity
ON customers.customerID=quantity.customerID
ORDER BY name;
```

The database contains 5 tables in this layout:

```
Customers
    columns
       customerID,
       name,
       address,
       phoneNumber,
       email

Ordercontents
    columns
        orderID,
        name,
        quantity
orders
    columns
       orderID,
       customerID,
       postcode,
       Date

products
    columns
       name,
       price

stores 
    columns
       postcode,
       address,
       phoneNumber
```

The numbered blanks have to be replaced to produce the outcome.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be a need for a sub-query/pseudo table. Use a left join on the three tables needed to get your answer.

```
SELECT 
    a.`name`,
    IF(SUM(b.`quantity`) IS NULL,0,SUM(b.`quantity`)) as `pizzas_ordered`
FROM Customers a
LEFT JOIN `orders` o
ON a.`customerID` = o.`customerID`
LEFT JOIN `Ordercontents` b
ON o.`orderID` = b.`orderID`
GROUP BY a.`customerID`
ORDER BY a.`name`;
```

If you also need the dollar amount for each customer, that could be easily added.

Comment: Is that just an extraordinarily convoluted way of saying COALESCE(SUM(...),0);